# dagger2 activityscope providing same object of injected dependencies with different activities

Tags: android, android-activity, dagger-2

Following code creates & shares **same** object of injected dependencies(`ViewsApiEnd` ) with different activities rather than creating different per activity.

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = HttpComponent.class, modules = ViewsApiModule.class)
public interface ViewsApiComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(SecondActivity activity2);
}
```

module:

```
@Module
public class ViewsApiModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public ViewsApiEnd providesGitHubInterface(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(ViewsApiEnd.class);
    }
}
```

Scope:

```
@Scope
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface ActivityScope{
    }
```

Full Source: [Github](https://github.com/RajuSE/CodeDagger2)(If anyone could fork & correct scope [issue](https://github.com/RajuSE/CodeDagger2/issues/5) it'll be helpful. Also checke  `void logInstances()` for verifying object creation )

How should I declare `ViewsApiComponent` if I want dagger2 to create **different** objects of injected deps( `ViewsApiEnd`) for different activities(`MainActivity` , `SecondActivity` )?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by different object you mean different instances and not different implementations.

The key to this is scopes and how you manage your components. In particular `ViewsApiComponent`.

Let's start with scopes. A scope in dagger is nothing but an annotation that tells dagger that during the life of a given component, as long as an object annotated with a given scope is required, the instance provided will always be the same. In other words, within the same component scoped dependencies will be singleton.

In your code, this `ActivityScope` is the scope tied to `ViewsApiEnd`. Now what people usually don't get about scopes is the first part of - "... as long as the component is alive scoped dependencies are singleton". Basically this says, if your component's instance remains the same, then all your scoped instances will be the same.

In your code this is the case because you pin `mViewsApiComponent` to the application class and you never recreate it. So in your activities when you do this:

```
// ...
((MyApp) getApplication()).getGitHubComponent().inject(this);
// ...
```

You're always using the same component, hence same scopes, hence same instance of `ViewsApiEnd`.

You need to make sure the scoped dependencies have a proper scoped handling. If you want a dependency that is different per activity, then you want to manage the component that takes care of this dependency on a **per activity** basis.

There's different ways of doing this. I think the simplest one in your case is to move the creation of `ViewsApiComponent` to your activities. Make sure you nullify the component in `onDestroy`. Something like this:

```
private ViewsApiComponent mViewsApiComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    getComponent().inject(this);
}

@Overrides
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mViewsApiComponent = null;
}

private ViewsApiComponent getComponent() {
  if (mViewsApiComponent == null) {
       mViewsApiComponent = DaggerViewsApiComponent.builder()
            .httpComponent(((MyApp) getApplication()).getNetComponent())
            .build();
  }
  return mViewsApiComponent;
}
```

*You can even put this code in a base activity and inherit from it in each activity.*

Important thing to notice is that the component is now managed by the activity, or better put it's tied to its life-cycle. This ensures the component lives during the life time of the activity and all scoped dependencies are the same within that activity. For another activity a new component will be created and the new object instances will be used, but within the activity they will remain the same.

Now I've explained all of this just for the sake of trying to help you out with components and scopes, but truth is that what you're currently providing in the component's modules are all objects that should indeed be singleton throughout the app's life. So in fact, the way you have it now is the most correct approach at least in my opinion.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help but I feel `@Overrides
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mViewsApiComponent = null;
}` is fallback option.

Comment: What do you mean with that? and why do you feel like that?

Comment: it solves problem hence I upvoted.. but let me get the response of this issue I posted on dagger2 GitHub.

Comment: If i get `ViewsApiComponent` from Application  `@ActivityScope` becomes same as  `@Singleton`, right? There won't be any difference between annotations?